# Caching a result across closure executions: the size for values of type `dyn Fn(u64) -> ...` cannot be known at compilation time

Tags: rust

At runtime, the following callback does not have a reference to the instance.
The callback binding must occur before the instance is created.
The instance is available when the callback is called.
But the callback needs to do an expensive operation to retrieve a function reference from the instance.
I want to cache this operation.

But I get the error : `doesn't have a size known at compile-time`, or `the size for values of type 'dyn Fn(u64) -> std::result::Result<u64, Trap>' cannot be known at compilation time`.
relating to the first line "let cache:...".

[Simplified playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=use%20std%3A%3Acell%3A%3ARefCell%3B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Arc%3A%3ARc%3B%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20cache%3ARc%3CRefCell%3COption%3CFn(u64)%20-%3E%20Result%3Cu64%2Cu64%3E%3E%3E%3E%20%3D%20Rc%3A%3Anew(RefCell%3A%3Anew(None))%3B%0A%7D)

```
fn fib_callback(instance_context: Rc<RefCell<InstanceContext>>) -> impl Fn(u64) -> u64 {
    // Closure to retain cache reference (Is there a better way?)
    let cache:Rc<RefCell<Option<Fn(u64) -> Result<u64,Trap>>>> = Rc::new(RefCell::new(None));

    return move |n: u64| -> u64 {
        let mut cache = cache.borrow_mut();
        if cache.is_none() {
            // This code is expensive and must be cached. At the time of binding the callback, instance is None, and is set later.
            let instance = &instance_context.borrow().instance.clone().unwrap();
            
            // This returns: impl Fn(u64) -> Result<u64,Trap>
            let f_fib = instance.get_func("test_fib_hostexec").unwrap().get1::<(u64), u64>().unwrap();

            cache.replace(Some(f_fib));
        }

        // Retrieve cache
        let f_fib = &cache.unwrap();
        
        //fib
        if n <= 1 { return 1; }
        return f_fib(n - 1).unwrap() + f_fib(n - 2).unwrap();
    }
}
```

Comment: A minimal reproducible example containing your function would be really helpful. Vaguely, I can only say that trait objetcs don't have a size known at compile time so you need to put them behind a pointer. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c773fd830255d6cba17d6aac526f0b00)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Option<Fn(u64) -> Result<u64, Trap>>` doesn't compile because `Fn(u64) -> Result<u64, Trap>` is not a type, it's a *trait*, and options are generic over concrete types.

The error message mentions `dyn` because for each trait `A` Rust automatically creates a *type* `dyn A` used for dynamic dispatch. Prior to edition 2018 Rust referred to that type *also* as `A` (without the `dyn`), which is still supported for backward compatibility. So when you write `Option<Fn...>`, Rust interprets that as referring to the `dyn Fn...` type corresponding to the `Fn...` trait. This doesn't compile because `dyn` types are unsized because they serve as stand-in for a type whose size and other fundamental properties will only be known at run-time. The only way to refer to a `dyn` is through a reference or a smart pointer, which works because referencing it automatically creates a [trait object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html).

In your case the `RefCell` likely needs to own the closures, so you can use a `Box` to hold them:

```
let cache: Rc<RefCell<Option<Box<Fn(u64) -> Result<u64, u64>>>>> = Rc::new(RefCell::new(None));
```

...which compiles in the simplified example. In your actual code you will need to change `cache.replace(Some(f_fib))` to `cache.replace(Some(Box::new(f_fib) as _))`, and possibly other modifications to satisfy the lifetimes.

Comment: This is also described here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-05-advanced-functions-and-closures.html